# No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'repeats'

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have this error when trying to make a timer that changes the displayed text.

```
if ([operation isEqualToString:@"/"]) if (n2 == 0)   
{   

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
    self.userIsTyping = NO;
    NSString *errorZeroIsNotDivisible = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%g Is not divisible in 0", n1];
    NSString *getBackToCurrentOperation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g %@", n1, operation];
    self.display.text = errorZeroIsNotDivisible;
    NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6 invocation:self.display.text = [getBackToCurrentOperation repeats:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is directing you to a mistake in your code.

```
+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:]
```

is the method you are expecting to call, however you have placed an assignment and inadvertant message call to getBackToCurrentOperation object.

Since getBackToCurrentOperation is an NSString type, the error is directing you to that class because your code is calling `-[NSString repeats:]` on the string getBackToCurrentOperation.

Comment: So i could make a timer that sets the displayed text?
I tried different things but I can't get it.
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: You can use the scheduled timer for this, but your code was using an asignment in the place of invocation

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't know how to use the NSTimer properly.
Now my code is running as I wanted